# R replace_na values conditionally by column with multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, na

My question is similar to other replace_na posts but I can't find the right combination of answers.

I have a dataframe with inflation rates for all countries over 8 years (wide format - countries as rows and years as columns).

1. Some countries have NAs for all 8 years (columns 3:10), and in that case I want to replace all NAs with the column mean

```
library(tidyverse)

sample %>% 
  mutate_if((rowSums(is.na[,3:10]))!=8, replace_na = colMeans(na.rm=T))
```

This is close but something is wrong.

2. Other countries only have NAs in some columns, in which case I want to replace NA with the previous year's value

```
library(zoo)
sample %>% 
  mutate_if((rowSums(is.na[,3:10]))!=8, replace_na = colMeans(na.rm=T)),
         is.na[,4:10], na.locf(fromLast = TRUE)))
```

Tried using na.locf from the zoo package but can't get it right with the other conditions

3. The final condition is that, if the NA is in the first year (2007), I want to replace it with the 2007 column mean instead of the next year (2008 was the financial crisis so all the inflation rates went nuts).

```
  mutate_if((rowSums(is.na[,3:10]))!=8, replace_na = colMeans(na.rm=T)),
         is.na[,4:10], na.locf(fromLast = TRUE)),
          is.na("2007"), replace = colMeans("2007", na.rm = TRUE))
```

But this is full of errors and I'm stuck trying to link all these conditions together - pretty new to ifelse statements. I'm trying to find a dplyr solution as that's the syntax I'm most familiar with, but maybe it's easier in base R or data.table

running R 3.6.1

```
sample <- structure(list(`Country Name` = c("Aruba", "Afghanistan", "Angola", 
"Albania", "Andorra", "Arab World", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", 
"Armenia", "American Samoa", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Australia"
), `Country Code` = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "ALB", "AND", "ARB", 
"ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "ASM", "ATG", "AUS"), `2007` = c(5.39162036843645, 
8.68057078513406, 12.2514974459487, 2.93268248162318, NA, 4.74356585295154, 
NA, NA, 4.40736089644519, NA, 1.41605259409743, 2.32761128891476
), `2008` = c(8.95722105296535, 26.4186641547444, 12.4758291326398, 
3.36313757366391, NA, 11.2706652380848, 12.2504202448139, NA, 
8.94995335353386, NA, 5.33380639820232, 4.35029854990047), `2009` = c(-2.13630037272305, 
-6.81116108898995, 13.7302839288409, 2.23139683475865, NA, 2.92089711805365, 
1.55980098148558, NA, 3.40676682683799, NA, -0.550159995508869, 
1.77111716621252), `2010` = c(2.07773902027782, 2.1785375238942, 
14.4696564932574, 3.61538461538463, NA, 3.91106195534027, 0.879216764156813, 
NA, 8.17636138473956, NA, 3.3700254022015, 2.91834002677376), 
    `2011` = c(4.31633194082721, 11.8041858089129, 13.4824679218511, 
    3.44283593170005, NA, 4.75316388885632, 0.877346595685083, 
    NA, 7.6500080785929, NA, 3.45674967234599, 3.30385015608744
    ), `2012` = c(0.627927921638161, 6.44121280934118, 10.2779049218839, 
    2.03642235579081, NA, 4.61184432206646, 0.662268900269082, 
    NA, 2.55802007757907, NA, 3.37688044338879, 1.76278015613193
    ), `2013` = c(-2.37226328015073, 7.38577178397857, 8.77781429332619, 
    1.92544399507649, NA, 3.23423783752364, 1.10111836375706, 
    NA, 5.78966778544654, NA, 1.05949782356168, 2.44988864142539
    ), `2014` = c(0.421637771012246, 4.67399603536339, 7.28038730361125, 
    1.61304235314414, NA, 2.77261158414198, 2.34626865671643, 
    NA, 2.98130868933673, NA, 1.08944157435363, 2.48792270531403
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compute a logical vector, `all.na` having one component per row which is TRUE if that row's numeric data is all NAs and FALSE otherwise.  Then use `na.aggregate` to fill in all-NA rows.  Also use na.aggregate on `2007`.  Then convert to long form and apply `na.locf0` by country and convert back to wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

all.na <- sample %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  { rowSums(is.na(.)) == ncol(.) }

sample %>% 
  mutate_at(-(1:3), ~ if_else(all.na, na.aggregate(.x), .x)) %>%
  mutate(`2007` = na.aggregate(`2007`)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -`Country Name`, -`Country Code`) %>%
  group_by(`Country Name`, `Country Code`) %>%
  mutate(value = na.locf0(value)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

or using only zoo:

```
library(zoo)

all.na <- apply(is.na(sample[grep("^2", names(sample))]), 1, all)

ix <- -(1:3)
sample.out <- sample
Fill <- function(x) ifelse(all.na, na.aggregate(x), x)
sample.out[ix] <- lapply(sample[ix], Fill)
sample.out$"2007" <- na.aggregate(sample.out$"2007")
sample.out[ix] <- t(apply(sample.out[ix], 1, na.locf0))
```

Comment: Clever, I think I follow most of this, but where in the ~na.locf0 statement does it say to replace with the nearest or previous value? If na.aggregate(.x) is replacing with the mean of that column where all cols are NAs, I don't understand how that piece (all.na, na.aggregate(.x), .x) replaces a single NA with the previous column.

Comment: This works, thank for the solution. I was just trying to figure out what each line does but I worked it out. I prefer the tidyr/zoo solution but both are good

Answer (score 1):

Tried to do the same by only using the tidyverse (dplyr and tidyr), this is what I got:

Created the Replacement according to condition 1. Column Means.

```
# Getting the Column Means to Replace according to Condition 1 and 3. 
replacement <- sample %>%
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%
    summarize_all( ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    #Transformed to List since it is a requirement for tidyr::replace_na()
    as.list()
```

Then I created everything into just one pipeline.

```
sample %>%
  pivot_longer(`2007`:`2014`, names_to = "year", values_to = "int_rate") %>%
  group_by(`Country Name`) %>%
  summarize(na_num = is.na(int_rate) %>% sum) %>%
  #Joining the number of NAs na_num as a new column
  left_join(sample, by = "Country Name") %>%
  #Replacing 2007 missing as a first value. Condition 3.
  mutate(`2007` = if_else(between(na_num, 1, 7) &
                            is.na(`2007`), replacement[[1]] , `2007`)) %>%
  #Making dataset wider 
  pivot_longer(`2007`:`2014`, names_to = "year", values_to = "int_rate") %>%
  group_by(`Country Name`) %>%
  #Using fill to impute NAs with the previous one. Condition 2.
  fill(int_rate) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = int_rate) %>%
  #Replacing Values when all values are missing. Condition 1.
  replace_na(replace = replacement)
```